# <br> that disappears if text has line break (without using white-space: nowrap)

Tags: html, css, line-breaks

I am trying to make a table that works on many mobile devices.  It is imperative that all `<tr>`s are of equal height & fairly compact.  Some text in various `<td>`s might flow onto a second line, but most of the time that doesn't happen.

```
<tr>
    <td class="col1">5</td>
    <td class="col2">
        <b>Some Data that can be very long</b>
        <br> 
        <br> 
        <div class="special1">
             More data
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

When the long line has to break into 2 lines, I would like one of my `<br>`s (or a comparable spacing solution) to disappear.  Is there any way to do this?  Maybe with a margin & max-height combo?

Edit: Can't believe I forgot to say this, but I can't use the `white-space` property.  On iOS the usage of this property results in table cell borders that don't collapse and end up having various thicknesses.  For example column one shows as the normal 1px thickness I want, but col2 is at least 2px thick.  So I am looking for an alternative method to control the height of each table row.

Comment: What does "my `<br>`" mean?  I think we need to see an actual example.

Comment: @JohnGordon I added an example.  Basically I am trying to make a line break go away if some text takes two lines.

Answer (score 1):

One solution to this problem could be to use the CSS property "line-height" to ensure that all rows have equal height.

You can also use the "white-space" property to control how text wraps within cells.

To make sure that line breaks disappear when text wraps onto a second line, you can use the "display" property and set it to "inline-block" for the table cells.

I recommend you use white-space css property.

Comment: Thank you Dev.  Your suggestion of using the white-space property is what I originally tried, I just completely blanked on that when posting.  iOS renders tables weirdly when that property is applied to a TD element so I need an alternative.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by adding a class to the "very long" data block:

CSS:

```
fixed-height {
    display: block;
    height: 2ex;
}
```

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td class="col1">5</td>
    <td class="col2">
        <b class="fixed-height">Some Data that can be very long</b>
        <br> 
        <br> 
        <div class="special1">
             More data
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Thus it always takes up an extra line and will fill the second line as needed.

[Learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#:%7E:text=px%20(pixels).-,Relative%20length%20units,-Relative%20length%20units) about the `ex` unit